# How to turn off annotation warnings in Flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype, nuclide-editor

I'm using Flow within Nuclide/Atom and I would really like to turn off the underline and gutter prompts for annotation on function parameters. How can this be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a good idea; if you ignore or suppress these warnings Flow may not be able to typecheck your code properly.

Answer (score 2):

Flow has a configuration option called `suppress_comment`. By default it's configured to ignore the following:

```
// $FlowFixMe
```

https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-suppress-comment-regex

Example:

```
// $FlowFixMe
function a(var1, var2, var3) {
    // Something here
}
```

If there are too many warnings, it may be worth considering either fixing them, or removing the `@flow` annotation from the specific file, so flow won't evaluate it.